# How to remove selected date saved when using multiple datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have problem went i using multipe date picker, if i select date for multidate pickers on same id , date picker always returns the latest date selected

Example on this image :
[preview selected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6YOo.jpg)

This is my html

```
$('#start_date').datepicker({
     format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
});
```

In the class html date picker add new class 'active' on tag 'td' class 'day'

Comment: How can datepicker install multiple widgets on same control?

Comment: i mean if a open date picker and select a date, latest date clicked  save on i open date picker again

Comment: thats how datepicker works, unless old selection is cleared out

Answer (score 0):

Set a default date for each ids:

```
$("#start_date").datepicker({defaultDate: new Date() });
```

or

```
$("#start_date").datepicker({defaultDate: "7/11/2011"});
```

do the same for stop_date and it should work

Comment: i want to make date picker remove the latest selected if ia open agai date picker

Answer (score 0):

i found solution just use

forceparse

```
$('#start_date').datepicker({
 format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
 forceParse: false,
});
```